# Amazon Linux machine - Ansible ansible_distribution* variables major release distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yum, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

I'm using **Ansible: 2.2.0.0**

### I have 3 machines:

Two vagrant boxes (one CentOS 7.x and one Ubuntu 14.04) and 
3rd box is an EC2 Amazon Linux instance (Amazon Linux AMI release
    2016.03).

On these boxes, I'm **running the following command** and getting valid output (as listed below):

**CentOS**:

```
[vagrant@myvagrant ~] $ ansible all -m setup -i "`hostname`," --connection=local -a "filter=ansible_distribution*"
myvagrant | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_distribution": "CentOS", 
        "ansible_distribution_major_version": "7", 
        "ansible_distribution_release": "Core", 
        "ansible_distribution_version": "7.2.1511"
    }, 
    "changed": false
}
```

**Ubuntu**:

```
vagrant@myubuntuvagrant:~$ ansible all -m setup -i "`hostname`," --connection=local -a "filter=ansible_distribution*"
myubuntuvagrant | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_distribution": "Ubuntu", 
        "ansible_distribution_major_version": "14", 
        "ansible_distribution_release": "trusty", 
        "ansible_distribution_version": "14.04"
    }, 
    "changed": false
}
vagrant@myubuntuvagrant:~$
```

**Amazon EC2 instance/box**:

```
$ ansible all -m setup -i "`hostname`," --connection=local -a "filter=ansible_distribution*"
ip-10-200-1-145 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_distribution": "Amazon", 
        "ansible_distribution_major_version": "NA", 
        "ansible_distribution_release": "NA", 
        "ansible_distribution_version": "2016.03"
    }, 
    "changed": false
}
```

In one of my Ansible playbook / templates/yum.repos.d.file.j2 file, I'm using `{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}` variable and using it's value in a .repo file for the `baseurl` property's value for CentOS/Amazon EC2 instance **only** i.e. `when: ansible_distribution == "CentOS" or ansible_distribution == "Amazon"`.

`baseurl=https://packagecloud.io/company/packages/telegraf/el/6/$basearch`

**PS:** I'm not looking for Ubuntu (as that part is working fine with using apt-get in my playbook for both setting the apt-get source list and installing the package).

**My question:**
Why ansible facter variable is not setting any valid valid for `ansible_distribution_major_release` version for Amazon EC2 instance? What `facter_*`/`ansible_*` can I use which will work in all 3 OS types.

**PS:** When I used `baseurl`'s value with `../el/6/..` in it (inside the yum.repos.d/target-pacakge.amazon-os.repo file), yum install worked fine for installing the package on Amazon linux box (though, using `../el/7/..` in baseurl didn't work). **See here for more details**: https://packagecloud.io/docs#os_distro_version (under heading: **Enterprise Linux (CentOS, RedHat, Amazon Linux)**)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use following, **set_fact**, you don't have to specifically handle **ansible_distribution_major_version** in tasks for all three OS types.

```
pre_tasks:
- set_fact: ansible_distribution_major_version=6
  when: ansible_distribution == "Amazon" and ansible_distribution_major_version == "NA"
```

Comment: Yep, that's true but how would I know whether it's 6 or 7? If it's 7 then yum repo file `baseurl` won't work using `..\el\6\..` in it's path, right.

Comment: @ArunSangal you'd have to do a bit of further parsing and comparing. For Amazon Linux 2, related to EL7, the version is just "2". Original amazon linux had versions in the form of "YYYY.MM". I know 2018.03 corresponds to EL6. I can't speak to earlier versions, as I never used them before now.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some relevant values from an Amazon Linux 2 docker image:

```
# docker images|grep amazon
amazonlinux                             2                   d656eea421ba        4 weeks ago         162MB
amazonlinux                             latest              d656eea421ba        4 weeks ago         162MB

# docker run --init --rm -it amazonlinux:2 cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"

After installing ansible within the docker image:
# ansible --version
ansible 2.7.2

# Relevant items from output of 'ansible -m setup'
ansible_distribution: Amazon
ansible_distribution_file_parsed: true
ansible_distribution_file_path: /etc/system-release
ansible_distribution_file_variety: Amazon
ansible_distribution_major_version: NA
ansible_distribution_release: NA
ansible_distribution_version: 2
ansible_os_family: RedHat
ansible_pkg_mgr: yum
ansible_service_mgr: sysvinit  # should this be 'systemd'?
ansible_system_vendor: NA
ansible_virtualization_role: guest
ansible_virtualization_type: docker
```

and on an actual EC2 Amazon Linux 2 instance:

```
[root@ip-xxx ~]# ansible --version
ansible 2.7.2

ansible_os_family: RedHat
ansible_pkg_mgr: yum
ansible_service_mgr: systemd
ansible_system: Linux
ansible_system_vendor: Xen
ansible_virtualization_role: guest
ansible_virtualization_type: xen
```